# How to check if a type in a string is a real type

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a string representation of a type, e.g. `"List<string>"`, or `"int"` ...

Is there a way to check if this is a real .net type ?

for example, if I have `"List<Crap>"`, then I want to return false, because `Crap` is not a real type in .net. If I have `"string"`, or `"Dictionary<string, object>"` then I want to return true.

Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you count as a "real type"? Only one in mscorlib.dll or System.dll? What about types you've defined in your own assemblies? What namespaces do you want to check against, too? You need to be *very* clear about your requirements here.

Comment: Also, as you list `int` and `string` about an example, what type aliases do you want to consider? The runtime has no knowledge of the C# keywords `int` and `string`, those types are actually called `System.Int32` and `System.String`, respectively. Do you want to include language-specific aliases such as `int` and `string`? If so, from which languages?

Comment: Just another note: checking namespaces can be fooled as there's nothing stopping you from declaring in `MyNotRealAssembly.dll` a `System` namespace. EDIT: I mean, checking namespaces _only_ and ignoring the assembly the type is in.

Comment: Getting types from strings is something you should do your very best to avoid altogether unless it's a requirement you absolutely can't get around.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I wouldn't use the word *fooled* in this context. Having an assembly name that does not match the root namespace of the type contained therein is an entirely valid thing to do in C#, and not an "obscure trick" or something like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Either I suppose - although I'm not too familiar with the difference, I think in simplistic terms I want to check against all namespaces except anything that I or anyone else have created .. I hope that's not too vague or stupid.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Fair enough; I didn't quite mean it in such a context as someone getting around it, just that that method of checking isn't sufficient because (as you said) it's not extraordinarily uncommon to see custom classes filling in bits of the BCL `System.*` namespaces.

Comment: @Sherlock: Well it's a matter of how much of the framework you want to include. Do you need `Dictionary<XElement, string>` to work, for example? What do you want to do about types that exist in more than one namespace?

Comment: What is the use case here?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Sherlock does my edited answer work for you at all? If not, could you comment with any errors you're getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g:

```
string typeString = "System.String";
if(Type.GetType(typeString) != null) 
{
    //It's a real type 
}
```

EDIT: One caveat, you must fully qualify the type with an [assembly qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if it's not in the current assembly.

EDIT2: Borrowing from Amson's answer below:

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()

bool isReal = types.Any(x=>x.FullName == typeString);
```

This would however still need some string manipulation to handle generics. As `List<String>.FullName` is:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]`

EDIT3: On the string manipulation front, I came up with this, starting with `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` as a base:

```
Type type2 = typeof(Dictionary<string, List<string>>);
string typeString = type2.FullName;
int endOfType = typeString.IndexOf('`');
string mainType = typeString.Substring(0,endOfType);
mainType = mainType.Split('.').Last(); // this equals "Dictionary"

var genString = typeString.Substring(endOfType + 3);
string[] generics = genString.Split('[', ']');
generics = generics.Where(s => s != "" && s!= ",").ToArray();
```

It's not there yet on the generics (although it's not *too* far off either), but we can now at least compare base types! (although we also need checks in here for if there are *no* generic parameters).

I'll update this later tonight when I'm home if I manage a solution.

**EDIT4.5: SUCCESS(ish)!!!**

The following code will convert the value in Type.FullName into something human readable:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a type's full name into a human readable string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to convert</param>
    /// <returns>Type formatted as follows: Dictionary<List<String>,Queue<Int32>>
    /// Or for an open generic (e.g. Action<,>) returns Action<,></returns>
    private static string ConvertTypeToReadableString(Type type)
    {
        string typeString = type.FullName;
        int endOfType = 0;
        if (typeString.Contains('`'))
        {
            //We have generic arguments
            endOfType = typeString.IndexOf('`');
            string mainType = typeString.Substring(0, endOfType);
            mainType = mainType.Split('.').Last(); // this equals "Dictionary"
            //Use this for namespace qualified names instead:
            //return typeString
            string result = mainType + "<";
            var genString = typeString.Substring(endOfType + 3);
            //Get number of generic arguments to expect.
            int argCount = 0;
            int tempArgCount = 0;
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= genString.Length && Int32.TryParse(genString.Substring(0, i), out tempArgCount))
            {
                i++;
                argCount = tempArgCount;
            }
            string[] generics = genString.Split('[', ']');
            generics = generics.Where(s => s != "" && s != "," && !s.StartsWith(",")).ToArray();

            if (generics.Length < argCount)
            {
                //Assume an open generic
                for(int x= 0; x< argCount-1; x++)
                {
                    result += ",";
                }
                result += ">";
            }
            else
            {
                result += ParseGenerics(generics, argCount) + ">";
            }
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            //No generic arguments
            return typeString.Split('.').Last();
            //Use this for namespace qualified names instead:
            //return typeString;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert generic arguments into simplified strings
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="generics">List of strings, each containing one generic argument.</param>
    /// <returns>Single string of format Item1,Item2,Item3<Item4,Item5></returns>
    public static string ParseGenerics(string[] generics, int genericArgs)
    {
        string result = "";
        int index = 0;
        while(genericArgs > 0)
        {
            string generic = generics[index];
            if (generic.Contains('`'))
            {
                //Another generic
                int genericIndex = generic.IndexOf('`');
                string mainType = generic.Substring(0, genericIndex).Split('.').Last();
                //Use this if you want namespace-qualified names:
                //string mainType = generic.Substring(0,genericIndex);
                int i = 1;
                //Get number of generic arguments to expect.
                int argCount = 0;
                int tempArgCount = 0;
                while (genericIndex + 1 + i <= generic.Length && Int32.TryParse(generic.Substring(genericIndex + 1, i), out tempArgCount))
                {
                    i++;
                    argCount = tempArgCount;
                }
                //Parse internal generics
                result += mainType + "<" + ParseGenerics(generics.Skip(index + 1).ToArray(),argCount) + ">";
                index += argCount;
            }
            else
            {
                //Get type name
                result += generic.Split(',').First().Split('.').Last();
                //Use this if you want namespace-qualified names:
                //result += generic.Split(',').First();
            }
            result += ",";
            genericArgs--;
            index++;

        }
        //remove trailing comma
        return result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
bool isRealType = false;
string typeString = "Dictionary<string,List<string>>".Replace(" ", string.empty).ToLowerInvariant();
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes();
isRealType = types.Any(t=> ConvertTypeToReadableString(t).ToLowerInvariant().Equals(typeString));
```

If you're expecting to put namespace-qualified names in (e.g. System.String instead of just String) uncomment the relevant comments.

The only thing you might want to do after this is use a lookup table to convert from the integral types to their class names (e.g int to Int32), but I leave that as an exercise for you.

EDIT 5: Just one remaining problem. My answer now works fine for converting, even with an open generic type, but you still need to account for the fact that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes();` is going to only return open generics, and to check that you have the right number of args inside your string. Very doable from what I've got here, but I have to sleep.

Comment: That's not going to work for `Dictionary<string, object>` for various reasons.

Comment: Yeah it becomes much harder if you want to allow generic parameters

Comment: What do you think the likelihood is that they'll be able to take what looks like an arbitrary string input and to ensure that it's assembly qualified?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that depends on usage. Their example uses only types in mscorlib which would be fine. Hence why I added the caveat.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Reflection will deal with that bit itself. If it doesn't work, it's not a correctly assembly-qualified type. Unless the assembly hasn't been loaded at all, in which case you have a whole new headache.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Could you do some string processing to convert "System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>" to "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String]]" or some equivalent? Would Type.GetType work then?

Comment: @NickUdell Generic parameters always have to be fully assembly qualified for some reason I don't fully understand

Comment: Edited answer with another option, but once again it will be heavy on string manipulation. Not impossible though, I think. If you strip the assembly, and then maybe split the name by the ` character, you might get somewhere. Happy to be proven wrong though :)

Comment: I think "some string processing" is an understatement. I'd expect it to be a *lot* of work to get to the stage where `Dictionary<string, object>` works.

Comment: Dictionary<string,object> would equal System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] which if you split by the ` character and by square brackets gets easier, at least.@Sherlock: Is it acceptable for the input string to be namespace qualified at least? e.g. System.Collections.Generic.List instead of List?

Comment: Added some basic string manipulation. It can extract the base type, still working on generic parameters.

Comment: Edited question. Think I've solved it, string manipulation and all. EDIT: Nope, not quite there, couple of edge cases to handle.

Comment: Edited question to add support for open generics, although you'll have to find some way of populating the converted string with the type's you're expecting (i.e. converting Action<> to Action<String>), but compared to the string manipulation I've done to get you to this stage, it shouldn't be *too* hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you object is not nullable you can use

```
item.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("System")
```

If not you can just create a list of system objects and then check if your object is in that list

```
 List<Type> sysTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
     .GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes().ToList();

 if (sysTypes.Contains(item.GetType())) {
     // do something usefull
 }
```

Comment: where are "item" and "i" coming from here?

Comment: I'm still confused where item is coming from here.

Comment: i did not give a complete answer, but it's obvious that he needs to convert his string to an abject i called it item

Comment: Yes, but that bit might be quite difficult (see my answer's comments for why) and is a large portion of the answer.